# why doesn't change the value of my input?

Tags: vue.js

I have an input where passing the value of my star-rating module. When i use my function with v-model, the value of my input change (for example '4'), but the value it's not read with my function @input.

My code in template:

```
<div v-if="question.element_type=='notation'">
    <star-rating 
         inactive-color="#4c514c" 
         v-bind:star-size="30"
         v-model="selectedNote"
         @rating-selected ="next"
         :rounded-corners="true"
         :show-rating="false">
     </star-rating>
    <textarea 
        v-model="selectedNote" 
        class="myTextarea" 
        maxlength="1"
        :name="'q'+question.id"
        @input="next">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

my two functions :

```
setRating: function(rating) {
                this.selectedNote = rating
            },
next(evt){
    this.selectedNote = evt.target.value
    if(evt.target.value.length)
        this.affichageSuivant = true 
    else
        this.affichageSuivant = false
},
```

and my state of seletedNote

```
selectedNote: 0,
```

Comment: Can u add this (evt.target.value) in console and check what is it returning??

Comment: I dont know your logic but i woldnt be @rating-selected ="setRating" ?